# classic asp not recognizing xPath contains() function

Tags: xml, xpath, asp-classic

I'm using classic ASP, XML and xPath to select some data and I'm trying to make a selection on the following xml where  the node id_attribut contains "xc".  So I would like to only select the first 2 attribut.

my xpath is :

```
"//attribut[contains(id_attribut,"xc")]"
```

but ASP is giving me the error:

> msxml3.dll error '80004005' Unknown method.
>   //attribut[-->contains(id_attribut<--,"xc")]
>   /products/list_products.asp, line 54

Is contains() not a valid function for xPath in classic ASP (not ASP.net)?

I have the following XML:

```
<attributes>    
<attribut>
     <id_attribut>xc_elite</id_attribut>
     <level>4</level>
     <pty>1</pty>
     <parent>xc</parent>
   </attribut>
<attribut>
     <id_attribut>xc_performance</id_attribut>
     <level>4</level>
     <pty>2</pty>
     <parent>xc</parent>
</attribut>
<attribut>
     <id_attribut>alp_elite</id_attribut>
     <level>4</level>
     <pty>1</pty>
     <parent>alp</parent>
</attribut>
</attributes>
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What happens when you try: //attribut[starts-with(id_attribut,"xc")]

Comment: That's not an ASP error - looks like an XML error.

Comment: An actual line of VBScript code would improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

MSXML3 isn't known for the quality of its error messages - try compiling it with a different processor to get better diagnostics.

I suspect the problem is your use of unescaped quotes around the second argument. If you use double quotes as the attribute delimiter, you must use single quotes around string literals in the XPath expression.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  The quotes are actually escaped in my code, I'm not sure why they didn't paste through to my message code block. I've been able to use escaped double quotes in all the rest of my xPath before this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today... :)
Probably some Win-sh*t updates changed something..

I use VBScript.. and I changed `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")` to `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")`.

It helped.